# How to use split in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to split first word in update query.

> -- TITLE: "Visual Studio"

```
UPDATE SET TITLE = TITLE.Split(' ')[0]
```

> -- RESULT: "Visual"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I don't understand.. I'm a beginner. Please help me :)

Comment: The reference docs are the best source of material for learning this from. Have a go using the reference and then ask if something about it is confusing.

Comment: Thank you! i successed!!
UPDATE RED0001T01 SET RED_NAME = (SELECT TOP 1 value FROM STRING_SPLIT(RED_NAME, ' '))

Comment: @안녀엉 Please _don't_ use that query.  `STRING_SPLIT` makes no guarantee about the _order_ of records in the table output.  It is possible that `TOP 1` might not be the first word in the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `SPLIT` function in SQL Server as far as I know.  There *is* a `STRING_SPLIT` function, in version 2016 or later, but that would not necessarily work here.  The reason it might not work as expected is that it generates a *table* as output, containing the individual terms, which are *not* ordered.

If you want to update the `TITLE` field to retain just the first word, consider using the base string functions:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET TITLE = SUBSTRING(TITLE, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', TITLE) - 1)
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ', TITLE) > 0;
```

The above logic handles the case where a given title might not have any spaces in it, i.e. it consists of just one word.  In this case, the update would just skip that record.

Comment: Compatibility level 130 now supports the ordinal column as an optional output.  See my example below.

Answer (score 0):

In `MS SQL Server` to solve it use `STRING_SPLIT` like there:

```
update t set 
  t.Title = a.First_Word
from Your_Table
outer apply (
  select top 1
    value as First_Word
  from t.TITLE.STRING_SPLIT(' ')
) as a
```

Or you can write some inline function for this:

```
create function Get_FirstWord(@words varchar(max))
returns varchar(max) as
begin
  declare @First_word varchar(max);

  select top 1
    @First_word = value
  from @words.string_split(' ');

  return @First_word;
end;
```

And later use it like that:

```
update Your_Table set 
  Title = Get_First_Word(Title)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server 2016+, another possible approach to split a string into substrings and get a substring by position, is to use [OPENJSON()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (it's not too complicated, even if you are not familiar with `JSON`).

First, transform input text into valid `JSON` array using `REPLACE()` and `STRING_ESCAPE()` (`'Visual studio'` into `'["Visual", "Studio"]'` for example). After that, use `OPENJSON()` with default schema to retrieve this `JSON` array as table, which has columns `key`, `value` and `type`. The `key` column contains the index of the element in the specified array, so you can get each element by index.

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   [Text] nvarchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   ([Text])
VALUES
   (N'Visu"al Studio'),
   (N'Visual Studio'),
   (N'Visual1 Studio'),
   (N'Visual2 Studio'),
   (N'Visual3 Studio'),
   (N'Visual[ Studio')
```

T-SQL:

```
UPDATE #Data
SET [Text] = (
   SELECT [value]
   FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT(N'["', REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE([Text], 'json'), N' ', N'","'), '"]'))
   WHERE [key] = 0
   -- or get other substring by index: WHERE [key] = 1
)
```

Output:

```
SELECT [Text] 
FROM #Data

-------
Text
-------
Visu"al
Visual
Visual1
Visual2
Visual3
Visual[
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your compatibility level.  If you have 130 or above, you can make use of T-SQL's latest STRING_SPLIT function, with the ordinal parameter.

E.g.

```
WITH cteExamples
    AS
    (
    SELECT StringToSplit = 'Visual Studio'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Jet Brains'
    )
    SELECT e.*,
        FirstValue = s.[value]
        FROM cteExamples AS e
            CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(e.StringToSplit, ' ', 1) AS s
        WHERE s.ordinal = 1;
```